# How does transaction ordering works in polygon blocks

Tags: polygon, txpool, mev, mev-searcher

Hello I am trying to do some easy dex arbitration but my transactions despite having enough `gasPrice` (or `maxPriorityFeePerGas, maxFeePerGas`) keep going way back sequentially in the block.

For example in this [block (40713528)](https://polygonscan.com/block/40713528) with `baseFeePerGas` of `196.930832708 Gwei` I am paying `403.92 Gwei` in my [transaction (0xd32ac12fe35193e02835ba31d1d631e244fbd28457c6ea04446dd8d87c65cad1)](https://polygonscan.com/tx/0xd32ac12fe35193e02835ba31d1d631e244fbd28457c6ea04446dd8d87c65cad1) and it happens to be second to last in the block. Where as [the second transaction](https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x0fa555e08f4178f9ad5f25d13f863ed13aa41a187be1dfa7f17def8386291a12) in the block pays only 227.247929998 Gwei and it is second :D

How can I optimise my transaction's position? Is it solely related to the latency? Does the number of nodes to which I submit the transaction improves likelihood of being founded faster?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I optimise my transaction's position? Is it solely related to the latency

You make a private deal with validators to include your transaction through MEV channels.

Validators really do not care about your arb transactions if they can make the same profit themselves.

Comment: Any ideas how to do this on polygon? For ethereum I knew about Flashbots but they don't support Polygon

Comment: Try Bloxroute, others.